# start/end date and time in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need a query output like the below table; 
This is a primary entry to a table and these records will be modified by a third party program which I have no control. Can anyone suggest a good sample?

```
ID | DATEIN              | DATEOUT            | STATUS
 1   02.02.2014 00:00:00   02.02.2014 23:59:59     1
 2   03.02.2014 00:00:00   03.02.2014 23:59:59     0
```

I tried

```
SELECT To_Char(To_Date(SYSDATE), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss PM'), 
       To_Char(date_add(To_Date(SYSDATE +1), INTERVAL -1 SECOND), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss PM') 
FROM dual
```

but this query throws an error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`.

Comment: Why are you applying `TO_DATE` to `SYSDATE`? It's allready have DATE datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `PM` if you want it to be in 24-hour format. And pay attention to the mask for minutes, it is `mi`, not `mm` as in your query. Also as already mentioned no need to convert `SYSDATE` to date as it is already of that datatype:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(SYSDATE), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:mi:ss') date_in,
       to_char(to_date(SYSDATE + 1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:mi:ss') date_out
  FROM dual;

DATE_IN             DATE_OUT
------------------- -------------------
11-03-2014 00:00:00 11-03-2014 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with DATE_ADD and TO_DATE functions (SYSDATE is already a DATE, no need of conversion ) , and also use `mi` to show minute instead of `mm` which is format specifier for month  as in:

```
SELECT To_Char(SYSDATE, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mi:ss PM'),
       To_Char((SYSDATE + 1) + INTERVAL '-1' SECOND, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mi:ss PM')
FROM dual
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not clear what you are trying to achieve from the above query but if parenthesis is your only problem then you gotta hit the query:

```
SELECT To_Char(To_Date((SYSDATE), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss PM')), 
   To_Char(date_add(To_Date(SYSDATE +1), INTERVAL -1 SECOND), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss PM') 
FROM dual
```